# Read byte array into bitmap

Tags: php, android, png, arrays

I have a server which provides an encrypted image (converted to base64 for transmission) to my android app. The encrypted image will sit on the SD card until the app receives the key (via QR code scan). Then the app will decrypt the image and display it. I've compared MD5 hashes along the way which implies that the data is getting correctly decrypted (original image byte array hash matches decrypted byte array hash).

The problem is that:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decrypted, 0, decrypted.length);
```

returns null.

The original image is PNG which should be recognized by BitmapFactory?

If the byte array hashes match is that confirmation that the data is being transmitted/decrypted OK?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well try to load the image bytes into the BitmapFactory without any encryption/decryption.
If its still happening, then the problem with the creation of the bytw array and we can know the cause was not caused by encryption/decryption.

Comment: Guess I can't trust the hashes then lol. I did echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("test.png")); which gave a string with a lot of spaces in front of it. I copied the text into a raw file and the app returned null

Comment: No, the raw file containing the string obtained from echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("test.png")); still gave null when trying to decode byte array. Maybe it has something to do with the spaces in front of the string? Null padding?

Comment: Then try using the java trim function. It will remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: The spaces are not included. Should they be?

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device Try what is donw in this tutorial. Here the path to the image is given and the php code is not used to provide a base 64 string. If this works then the problem is caused when php converts into base 64

Comment: Working! :-) The tutorial worked OK. I was encrypting base64_encode(file_get_contents()). Must have been messing up somewhere. I'm now encrypting file_get_contents() and it seems to be OK. Thanks!